# Facebook Business Integration not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

In Facebook settings, there is a "Business integration" page and I would like to add a business app to the list, but there is not button to add any business apps.

Here you can see the "Business integration" page for your Facebook user:

https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=business_tools&ref=settings

I also tried to use Facebook Login and Javascript SDK to integrate with the external app (administered by a different Facebook user), putting the app id of the external app in the following code:

```
 <script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v11.0&appId=[app id of the app I want to integrate with]&autoLogAppEvents=1"  nonce="UE0mtp2w"></script>

 <div class="fb-login-button" data-width="" data-size="large" data-button-type="continue_with" data-layout="default" data-auto-logout-link="false" data-use-continue-as="false"></div>
```

I logged in with my own user and the login works, but after I can't see the app in the "Business integration" page. Instead, the app is appearing under the "Apps and websites page" here:

https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications&ref=settings

Should the app be created in a different way to appear under "Business integration"? Or should the login be done in a different way? I can't find much information online on how to do a Facebook Business integration. Essentially, what I'm trying to do is to have an external app to be able to access information in pages created by my Facebook user.

Comment: I'm guessing that probably depends on which app type you chose during the initial setup, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/create-an-app#step-2--choose-an-app-type

Comment: The app type is "Business" so it should be correct

Comment: Might also depend on whether you go with individual or business verification when the app gets released, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/release

Comment: The app is not released yet. Do I need an app review from Facebook to make the integration successfull?

Comment: I don't know what exactly the point of "business integration" is supposed to be in the first place, resp. what exactly that is supposed to mean. I see two of my own apps in that tab, but I never did anything specifically to make them show up there. Could depend on what permissions the app asks for, I suppose? As long as it only asks for user profile related permissions, it might fall into the "apps & websites" category, and when it starts asking for page management related permissions, that makes it "business" ...? Not sure really.

Comment: Yeah, I can see my own app as well under "business integration" but not the external apps (which end up under "apps and websites" instead). I'm trying now with an app review process to see if that changes the situation (asking advanced access for page_read_engagement permission). If they appear in "business integration" I would expect to be able to use the access token to get a page token and in that way access the information from the business page associated to the external app (as they have the same administrator).